# How to deselect radiobutton when dropdown value is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have 2 radio buttons and a drop down list under option 1 and option 2. the user can either select the radio button or the drop down list.

**option 1**

```
radiobtn1
radiobtn2
```

**option2**

```
dropdownlistbox
```

the radiobtn1 under option1 is checked as default. When the user select the value from the dropdown list, both the radio buttons should be disabled or it should deselects the radiobtn1 which is checked as default.

```
            <tr><td>option1</td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rdo" GroupName="Month" Text="radiobtn1" runat="server /></td>
            <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rdo2" GroupName="Month" Text="radiobtn2" runat="server /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>option2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddMonYear_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem  Text="opt1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="opt2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </td></tr>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
rdo.Checked=true;
if (ddMonYear.SelectedValue.Length.ToString() != "0")
        {
            rdo.Checked = false;
            rdo.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rdo.Checked = true;
        }
}
```

The above code doesnt work. the radiobtn 1 is not deselecting when i select the value from the drop down.

Help me in correcting my code.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it should be client script. Why don't you try to do it with JS?

Comment: Why are you casting `Length` to a string and comparing it to `"0"`? Why not just `ddMonYear.SelectedValue.Length != 0`?

Comment: If i cast that way.. I am getting an error which says                 Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

Comment: @Uriil.. I'm new to this programming field.. I don't know how to do it with JS.. Help me if u can.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

On your dropdown box, add this code (autopostback)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddMonYear_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack=True">
```

What this does is keep the value of the dropdown box. Each time your page is loaded, the dropdown box gets the default value before your pageload event fires. give that a try.

Comment: Is this correct??                                            protected void ddMonYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddMonYear.SelectedValue.Length.ToString() != "0")
        {
            rdo.Enabled = false;
        }
    }